# How to fill a column to differentiate a set of rows from other rows in a group in Impala?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I have the following table in Impala.

```
|LogTime|ClientId|IsNewSession|
|1      |123     |1           |
|2      |123     |            |
|3      |123     |            |
|3      |666     |1           |
|4      |666     |            |
|10     |123     |1           |
|23     |666     |1           |
|24     |666     |            |
|25     |444     |1           |
|26     |444     |            |
```

I want to make a new table as follows:

```
|LogTime|ClientId|IsNewSession|SessionId|
|1      |123     |1           |1        |
|2      |123     |            |1        |
|3      |123     |            |1        |
|3      |666     |1           |1        |
|4      |666     |            |1        |
|10     |123     |1           |2        |
|23     |666     |1           |2        |
|24     |666     |            |2        |
|25     |444     |1           |1        |
|26     |444     |            |1        |
```

Basically, I want to make `SessionId` column that has a unique session ID per set of rows until there's a value of `1` in `IsNewSession` column after group by `ClientId`, to differentiate different sessions per `ClientId`.

I've made `IsNewSession` column to do so, but not sure how to iterate on the rows to make `SessionId` column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(isnewsession) over (partition by clientid order by logtime) as sessionid
from t;
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this! Thanks for the clear cut answer! :)